# Connecting Android Studio Project to a Database

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlite, android-studio, database-connection

So i am new to this whole android development using Android Studio. I am making a college library system management application. I am done with creating the login and register activity with an sqlite database connection. But all the tutorials that i have seen, the data inputted by the user gets stored only in the mobile itself. I want a way so that the data that is entered on every device can be accessed by me and is stored in one place. Also, i would be needing to list down a lot of books, is sqlite good for this?

Comment: There are many guides/tutorials out there you can find a step by step explanation for this. check [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/creating-sqlite-databases-in-your-app-719366/) also i would suggest you read the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section since you are a new contributor

Comment: Far too broad a question and recommendations for products are not allowed.

Comment: [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: ok so i need to use a client server sql.